# load a style for an image inside a div using Itextsharp

Tags: c#, html, itext

I am trying to convert an html page into pdf file using itextSharp but I am having a problem in assigning a css style for an image

example :

```
<body>
...
<div class='ticketFont2'><img src='example.png' /></div>
...
</div>
```

I tried to do this

```
styles.LoadTagStyle("img ticketFont2", "width", "30px");
```

what I've did actually can be written like this in css `.ticketFont2 img { width:30px }`
but it didn't work.
Am I missing something here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadTagStyle` is part of `HTMLWorker` which does not really support CSS despite classes that appear like they should. You can use basic HTML attributes as well as class-based targeting and that's about it. That's why `HTMLWorker` **has been deprecated** in favor of `XMLWorker` and you are encouraged to switch to that.

With `HTMLWorker` you can do very simple and broad HTML tag targeting like this:

```
//Set all IMG tags to be 100 pixels wide
styles.LoadTagStyle(iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.IMG, iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.WIDTH, "100px");
```

You can also do class based targeting but you can only target the entire contents of the class attribute.

```
//Change the width of all elements that have the exact (not contains) class of myimage
var html = "<img class='myimage' src='...' />";
styles.LoadStyle("myimage", iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.WIDTH, "100px");
```

This **will not** work:

```
var html = "<img class='myimage tickets' src='...' />";
styles.LoadStyle("myimage", iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags.WIDTH, "100px");
```

When using `LoadTagStyle` and `LoadStyle`, if you can't find the HTML tag or attribute in `iTextSharp.text.html.HtmlTags` then iTextSharp is not aware of it and it won't work. Also, make sure that you don't have any `<hr/>` tags in your HTML, `HTMLWorker` doesn't like those either. If you can live with these limitations then `HTMLWorker` might work for you but it is not maintained anymore and is already 5+ years old. Like I said, you should probably look into `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: thank you for the wonderful reply Chris .appreciate your help ^-^